# mysql fulltext search with partial matches

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table containing all US cities. The structure and sample row looks like:

```
| id    | zip   | state | city   | lat       |  lng        |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 29431 | 82732 | WY    | Wright | 43.829349 | -105.532327 |
```

The goal is to build an `AJAX autocomplete` search that will check input against `zip`, `state` or `city`. These are some searches I've done and the corresponding results:

```
- wright
// returns all records containing wright as city

- 82732
// returns a single matching record

- wrig
// returns all records that partially match

- wright wy
// returns nothing
```

So the last query returns nothing, yet I need it to return the only matching record.

The search query in use where the terms with `+` and `*` are generated by PHP:

```
MATCH (zip, state, city) AGAINST ('+wright* +wy*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

So how can I modify this search so that searches such as `wright wy` will only return the exact matching record, `NOT` including other locations in the results?

Also it would be nice but not at all necessary if the order of the terms didn't matter. ie `wy wright` still returns valid results.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you mean by "ONLY return the exact record"?

Comment: If I type `wright wy` I shouldn't get results that have other states in them. I should only receive the record that matches `wright` as the city and `wy` as the state.

Answer (score 0):

How about a two-step search.  First do a split of RIGHT(entry,2) which you first search for against only the State column for a match.  If it matches, then you remove 2 characters and do a search for city on the remaining.  After the strip, you continue with your existing code.

If no state found, then proceed to your existing code directly.

In practice, I would also put a step if the state is found to strip both right ',' and ending spaces.

Arno